# How can I log into multiple accounts at the same time using the Google Api PHP Client

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Background: We've got two Accounts that each hold several profiles.
I am developing an application in PHP using the [provided API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/).
I can successfully retrieve data from both accounts separately, but whenever I instantiate the Google_Client object a second time (using a different variable name, of course), it instantly logs me out of the first account and overwrites the first account's settings.
Has anyone successfully managed to log into two accounts at the same time using the PHP API Client and could give me a hint on how to accomplish that?
Relevant code sections:

```
$client1    = new Google_Client();
$client1    ->setAssertionCredentials($omitted);
$client1    ->setClientId($id);
$client1    ->setAccessType('offline_access');
$gaClient1  = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
//I can now successfully query the Analytics API, but when I do this
$client2    = new Google_Client();
//and query gaClient1 again, it throws a "you must login/401"-error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the api uses caching with files to handle request. Now when the second client is created, it is using the same cache folder and thus it is overwriting the previous settings.

now in your config.php is the following:

```
'ioFileCache_directory'  =>
    (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir') ?
        sys_get_temp_dir() . '/Google_Client' :
    '/tmp/Google_Client')
```

This is the part that is always returning the same result. When creating a client, you can send in your own config array and it will be combined with the master. So you could use:

```
$client1    = new Google_Client(array('ioFileCache_directory'  => '/tmp/dirclient1'));
$client2    = new Google_Client(array('ioFileCache_directory'  => '/tmp/dirclient2'));
```

Also in your code you created a `$client1`, but later on you use `$gaClient1  = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);`.  Shouldnt that be `$gaClient1  = new Google_AnalyticsService($client1);`?

Comment: Thank you very much, I had already tried this, but I will look into it again.